# Report Side By Side

Tags: reporting-services

I've managed to create a report template and use it inside another report, as a method of replicating a "template"...
The filled template is like this:
[image: template]
As you can see, this is not a wide template, and i can fit 3 of it on a regular page... my problem here is that the best i could achieve so far is vertical replication!!!

What i'm looking for here is a way to say "fill all the 'columns', then, move to the following line"

Anyone ever managed to do this?

Details:

- Using SSRS 2008 R2
- Using BI tools for VS 2013

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ideas that spring to mind.

1. Add three columns to the report via the Report.Columns property and have the detail fill top to bottom then left to right. (This may not be ideal as you stated you want a left to right, to bottom flow).
2. Duplicate any number of mailing labels samples on the internet substituting your sub-report as the detail.
3. Create 3 Table's with three detail data sources and have the data source return the id's for your sub report ordered in a Take(1) Skip(2) left to right, up to down fashion, basically three partitions of data ordered by some value.
4. Create a Table with three columns and place a sub report in each column. Have the data return in a A-B-C | D-E-F | G-H-J fashion.
5. Create a Table with one column and place a column group on a value that will return 1-3 for your detail records, pushing your columns out to desired column width.

Comment: Suggestions 1-2 are the easiest to implement.  I was using a report just yesterday that does this!